# CakePHP remove unwanted relationship

Tags: cakephp, has-many, database-relations

I create some relations `Model_One hasMany Model_Two`.

I create some form with `Model_One` fields and a three fields likes `Model_Two.0.name`,  `Model_Two.1.name`,  `Model_Two.2.name`.

In `beforeSave` or `beforeValidate` (no matter) of `Model_2` I would like remove relations when `name` it's empty. How to do this?

After saving my results should look like this:
Saved fields from `Model_One`
Saved fields from `Model_Two` with keys, for example 0 and 2 (because `Model_Two.1.name` was empty).

Comment: Removing relations? To me it looks more like you want to exclude data-sets from being validated/saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Model->unbindModel() to unbind models dynamically

Refer the below links for more details

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_unbindModel

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me eg. `$this->User->unbindModel(
            array('belongsTo' => array('Category', 'BodyHeight'))
        );`